# Is there any way to sort nested lists without using operator.itemgetter?

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I have a file that i'm reading in, then creating nested lists that i want to then sort on the 4 element(zipcode)

```
jk43:23 Marfield Lane:Plainview:NY:10023
axe99:315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B:New York:NY:10027
jab44:23 Rivington Street, Apt. 3R:New York:NY:10002
ap172:19 Boxer Rd.:New York:NY:10005
jb23:115 Karas Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
jb29:119 Xylon Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
ak9:234 Main Street:Philadelphia:PA:08990
```

Here is my code:

```
ex3_3 = open('ex1.txt')
exw = open('ex2_sorted.txt', 'w')

data = []
for line in ex3_3:
    items = line.rstrip().split(':')
    data.append(items)
print sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(4))
```

Output:

```
[['jb23', '115 Karas Dr.', 'Jersey City', 'NJ', '07127'], ['jb29', '119 Xylon Dr.', 'Jersey City', 'NJ', '07127'], ['ak9', '234 Main Street', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '08990'], ['jab44', '23 Rivington Street, Apt. 3R', 'New York', 'NY', '10002'], ['ap172', '19 Boxer Rd.', 'New York', 'NY', '10005'], ['jk43', '23 Marfield Lane', 'Plainview', 'NY', '10023'], ['axe99', '315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B', 'New York', 'NY', '10027']]
```

this all works fine, I just wonder if there is a way to do this without using "import operator"?

Comment: Why would one not want to use any `import`?

Comment: @naeg: I think the OP means: without importing the `operator` module.

Comment: As noted below, you can use `lambda`.  But the whole point of `operator.itemgetter` is for use cases like yours.

Comment: @larsmans: yeah, but `operator` is part of the standard library. The only thing I could imagine that he uses Python <2.4. OR that he thinks he shouldn't use `import`, which would be nonsense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh yes, there is a way:

```
print sorted(data,key=lambda x: x[4])
```

Answer (score 4):

A rough workalike would be:

```
print sorted(data, key=lambda items: items[4])
```

but `operator.itemgetter` is a bit faster. I'm using this program to benchmark both approaches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import timeit

withlambda = 'lst.sort(key=lambda items: items[4])'
withgetter = 'lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(4))'

setup = """\
import random
import operator
random.seed(0)
lst = [(random.randrange(100000), random.randrange(100000), random.randrange(100000), random.randrange(100000) ,random.randrange(100000))
       for _ in range(10000)]
"""

n = 10000

print "With lambda:"
print timeit.timeit(withlambda, setup, number=n)

print "With getter:"
print timeit.timeit(withgetter, setup, number=n)
```

It creates a random list of 100,000 5-item tuples and then runs `sort()` on the list 1,000 times. On my MacBook Pro with Python 2.7.2, the `withlambda` version runs in about 55.4s and `withgetter` runs in about 46.1s.

Note that as the lists grow large, the time spent in the sorting algorithm itself grows faster than the time spent fetching keys. Therefore, the difference is much greater if you're sorting lots of little lists. Running the same test with a 1,000 item list repeated 100,000 times yields 22.4s for `withlambda` vs. 12.5s for `withgetter`.

Comment: Actually, not a great deal faster on random lists of 100,000 elements: some 8% faster.

Comment: I got about 18% faster on lists of 100,000 elements vs 41% faster on lists of 10,000 elements. I guess that makes sense as the overhead of sorting itself grows faster than the length of the list. Replacing `sorted()` with `map()` gave a 55% speedup. Moral: both are fast. itemgetter is faster. Pick the one that's most readable to you unless you must have the absolute fastest.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Thanks, I read up on 'operator' i see the benefit, but was interested in not using for testing sake. thanks!

Comment: @KirkStrauser: which Python version is that? I keep getting this ~8% speedup on Python 2.7.2, which a list of lists of random numbers, timed with IPython's `%timeit`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: thanks. I'd used `sorted` rather than `list.sort` for my benchmark. I'd already given you a +1, btw :)

Comment: @larsmans Ah, that might do it since it also has to manage list allocation, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Construct or reorganize your sublist so that the thing you want to sort on is first. In your case, ZIP code, instead of being element 4, should be element 0. Then you can just sort them.

Of course the suitability of this ordering for other uses of the data must also be considered.